# Unable to programmatically set Graphic Location in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

In Crystal Reports 2008, there's a "Graphic Location" image property where it can be set to a file path so when the report gets run, it uses the selected picture file instead of the one on the report. I tried setting this via the .NET API, but it's only working some of the time.

In the report itself, I've set Graphic Location to `{@LogoPath}`, then when I run the report via .NET API, I set `{@LogoPath}` to the filename of the picture. I've put the formula on the report itself, and it's indeed getting set to the correct filename, but the image on the report doesn't always update. It would consistently show up for some time, then consistently not show it again.

Comment: Did you get an answer for this? I have a subreport with 4 sections, each with an OLEObject with Graphic Location set to a Parameter coming from the main report.
The subreport also has a parameter which hides/shows sections. The first time the report is run, logo is shown correctly.
On subsequent runs, if the hidden Section changes, no logo appears. Is this similar to your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up using, the code is in Delpi Prism. One of the awkward thing to deal with is if the image being replaced is different size to the image on the report, Crystal doesn't resize it correctly. The other problem was I needed to free the picture object manually otherwise Crystal sometimes doesn't display it on the report.

```
method SetShadingAndLogo(const AReport:ReportDocument);
var
  LogoPath:String;
  PicObj:PictureObject;
  Logo:System.Drawing.Image;
  PicRatio:Double;
  ContWidth, ContHeight:Double;
  ContainerRatio:Double;
  NewDimension:Double;
  PosAdj:Integer;
  Scale:Double;
begin
  for each Section:Section in AReport.ReportDefinition.Sections do
  begin
    for each RptObj:ReportObject in Section.ReportObjects do
    begin
      if RptObj.Name.StartsWith('LOGO', StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) and
        (RptObj.Kind = ReportObjectKind.PictureObject) then
      begin
        //set to company logo
        LogoPath := "C:\logo.jpg";
        PicObj := RptObj as PictureObject;

        if not System.IO.File.Exists(LogoPath) then
          PicObj.ObjectFormat.EnableSuppress := true
        else
        begin        
          Logo := System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(LogoPath);

          //work out the aspect ratios of the image and the container
          PicRatio := Double(Logo.Width) / Double(Logo.Height);

          //convert twips to pixels
          //96 is the default dpi for Windows, but should really check Windows settings
          //instead of hard coding
          ContWidth  := Double(TwipsToPx(PicObj.Width, 96));
          ContHeight := Double(TwipsToPx(PicObj.Height, 96));

          ContainerRatio := ContWidth / ContHeight;

          // adjust the size of the container on the report to maintiain the original
          // image's ratio
          if PicRatio > ContainerRatio then 
          begin
            // reset the vertical position to remain centred on the original location

            // get the new height of the container (in pixels)
            NewDimension := (ContWidth / Logo.Width) * Logo.Height;

            // get the movement (in twips)
            PosAdj := PxToTwips(Integer((ContHeight - NewDimension) / 2), Integer(Logo.VerticalResolution));

            // adjust the position
            PicObj.Top := PicObj.Top + PosAdj;

            // picture is wider so adjust the height accordingly
            // need to scale using the logo's dpi to resize correctly
            Scale := Double(PicObj.Width) / Double(PxToTwips(Logo.Width, Integer(Logo.VerticalResolution)));
            PicObj.Width := Integer(PicObj.Width * Scale);
            PicObj.Height := Integer(PicObj.Height * Scale);
          end
          else 
          begin 
            // picture is taller and needs to be scaled to height
            // reset the horizontal position to remain centred on the original location

            // get the new width of the container (in pixels)
            NewDimension := (ContHeight / Logo.Height) * Logo.Width;

            // get the movement (in twips)
            PosAdj := PxToTwips(Integer((ContWidth - NewDimension) / 2), Integer(Logo.VerticalResolution));

            // adjust the position
            PicObj.Left := PicObj.Left + PosAdj;

            // picture is taller and needs to be scaled to height
            // need to scale using the logo's dpi to resize correctly
            Scale := Double(PicObj.Height) / Double(PxToTwips(Logo.Height, Integer(Logo.VerticalResolution)));
            PicObj.Width := Integer(PicObj.Width * Scale);
            PicObj.Height := Integer(PicObj.Height * Scale);
          end;

          //must free the logo, otherwise Crystal sometimes doesn't display it on report
          Logo.Dispose;

          for each fm:FormulaFieldDefinition in AReport.DataDefinition.FormulaFields do
          begin
            if fm.Name.Equals("LogoPath") then
              fm.Text := """"+LogoPath+"""";
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

method TwipsToPx(const AValue, ADpi:Integer):Integer;
begin
  //convert to twips using specified dpi, 96 is Windows' default dpi
  Result := System.Convert.ToInt32(Double(AValue) * ADpi / 1440);
end;

method PxToTwips(const AValue, ADpi:Integer):Integer;
begin
  //convert to pixels using specified dpi, 96 is Windows' default dpi
  Result := System.Convert.ToInt32(Double(AValue) * 1440 / ADpi);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my [Crystal Reports: Dynamic Images](http://cogniza.com/wordpress/2010/03/15/crystal-reports-dynamic-images/) posting.

Comment: Doesn't help unfortunately. I've already set the Graphic Location in the report to be a formula, as in the example you posted.

Only difference is they use a parameter formula instead of a regular formula, which isn't suitable for this because it'll prompt the user for the image location each time. I need my program to set the correct image without prompting the user.

Comment: Is the display-consistency issue at all correlated to using saved data vs. refreshing the data?

Answer (score 0):

In Graphics Location formula, you might want to do like as follow:-

```
{?imageUrl}
```

You can set this parameter in your CS file dynamically by doing as follow:-

```
 ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
 ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
 ParameterDiscreteValue parameterValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

 paramField.Name = "imageUrl";
 parameterValue.Value = "**URL FOR IMAGE**";
 paramField.CurrentValues.Add(parameterValue1);

 paramFields.Add(paramField);
```

In Report, Create "imageUrl" Parameter field. By doing as follow :-

1) Go to report and open Field Explorer on your left. If its not there you can get it by going 
Crystal Report >> Filed Explorer.

2) Right click on Parameter Field and click on "New"

3) Give Parameter name as "imageUrl". In "Value Option" set "Prompt With display only" and "Optional Prompt" to false.

This should work. 
Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. When I load the report, even though I'm clearly passing the parameter, it prompts me for the parameter anyway. Any idea?